# How to Scrape Page HTML and follow Next Link in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape a website for research, and I'm stuck. I want the scraper to read the page source, and append that to a local HTML file so I can analyze the data off-campus. I have experimented with `BeautifulSoup` and `Scrapy`, but I have found that I need to use `Selenium` to interact with the page to navigate through my university's authentication system. (I'm not including that code, because it's tangential to my question.)

When I run the script it navigates to the page and clicks the link, but it only saves the first page's HTML. It then duplicates and appends that page's HTML every time it click on the link.

How do I use `Selenium` to click on the next page link, scrape the HTML, and save to file until I reach the last page?

```
source = driver.page_source

while True:
    with open("test.html", "a") as TestFile:
        TestFile.write(source)
        try:
            driver.implicitly_wait(200)
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li.next').click()
        except AttributeError:
            break
```

Edit: I added the AttributeError to the except and received the following error.

> selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message:
>   stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

My assumption is that I need to slow down the `.click()`, which is why I originally had the implicit wait, but that doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

Comment: get rid of your naked except and you'll get a much more informative error message

Comment: Thanks n1c9, I added an AttributeError to the except and it gave me the error code I added above: StaleElementReferenceException.

Comment: is there any pop-in on the page or anything like that? or does it just flip to the next page as normal? Also, `implicitly_wait(num)` is supposed to be set when you initialize the webdriver, but that's just a stylistic thing.

Comment: It flips through the pages as normal until it gets to page 8 or 9 then it throws the stale element exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the `page source` to `source` variable inside the while loop.

```
source = driver.page_source

while True:
with open("test.html", "a") as TestFile:
    TestFile.write(source)
    try:
        driver.implicitly_wait(200)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li.next').click()
        source = driver.page_source
    except AttributeError:
        break
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped, but now I'm getting duplicates in my output for each page. For example it outputs: Page1Page1 Page1Page2Page2Page2Page3Page3

Comment: After clicking next link make your script to wait for some time and then get the page source.

Comment: I've added a wait, like you suggested, and it appears to be working now. Thanks, @SudharsanSelvaraj

Comment: Glad to help you!!

Comment: If this helps you then make sure to accept the answer:)